# Android Virtual Device - Can't access basic OS features / Internet

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I'm new to the Android OS and I am having trouble interacting with a virtual device. I've installed the Android SDK + Java + Eclipse and I'm trying to get a virtual device running and debug an apk I have.

I create a AVD and start it up and get this basic screen below but none of the other Android OS options you'd see on a standard phone. I can't even really control this device as the buttons seem to have no effect. I can't get into settings or see default installed applications, etc..

What am I doing wrong? I'd expect to have a basic clean Android OS startup when I launch these virtual devices but I get this funky screen and can't do anything with it, controls don't seem to work.

Worth noting I am doing this from a VMWare Workstation running Windows 2012 R2, not sure if there are issues if I'm running this all in a VM.

[image]

---

UPDATE:
OK so it appears I was using the Android 4.4W which I think is for wearable devices and why the OS was basically empty. I changed it to Android 4.4.2 x86 by cloning a Nexus 5 and now I just get a blank screen when I try to start the emulator. Here is a screenshot, any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:
You are using Android Wear API target, please try with regular android API (L preview or API 19 or below). I was able to reproduce your issue if i used Android Wear Target, it works if i used non-wear target. Android wear target is for 'wear' device types.

---

- When configuring the AVD, you can pick different "skins" , please see below highlighted in redbox

[image: android emulator AVD skins]

If you are using a custom (or vendor) defined device type, go into `AVD Manager -> Device Definitions` and double-click your device entry, it will open the below window, make sure `Buttons` tab says `Software`

- You can also navigate the [emulator UI with keyboard shortcuts](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#KeyMapping), often quicker this way.**

Comment: OK that might help the input (will try now) but still the device seems like a different version. See how your UI has the phone icon, people icon, etc? Why does mine not have that? I just have an empty home screen...

Comment: What is your `Target` and are you using one of the existing `Device` ? In my screenshot above, I use API 19, and Nexus 5 device . Your screenshot says Samsung galaxy device, I would test with Nexus 5 device type to rule out this issue.

Comment: Found it. Was using the Andriod 4.4W which apparently means "Wearable" and its a slimmed down OS? Damn I'm an Android n00b. :) Thanks for the pointers. One last question, how do I get the AVD to be a normal size on my screen? It's currently tiny, hard to see / control...

Comment: Crap spoke too soon... Still having issues, now slightly different. Updating main question.

Comment: Since you are using VMware Virtual Machine, try disabling `Use Host GPU` in AVD configuruation. It will take some time for Android emulator first time it boots a new AVD, so please wait for few minutes.

Comment: I had to actually pick a Skin other than dynamic hardware controls and now I can see and interact with the emulator. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A. Ashoke is right about using skins, you may choose a skin when you create or edit the emulator. Here is a screen-shot. Check the 'skin' dropdown. (It may not be available for some 'devices' you select here. 
[image]

You are using VMWare, so you might be behind a proxy. You may need to provide proxy, using following steps -

1. Click on Menu
2. Click on Settings
3. Click on Wireless & Networks
4. Go to Mobile Networks
5. Go to Access Point Names
6. Here you will Telkila Internet, click on it.
7. In the Edit access point section, input the "proxy" and "port"
8. Also provide the Username and Password, rest of the fields leave them blank.

When you will load it for the first time, it may again ask for your credentials. So provide there as well.